# organizes items by category

Tags: javascript

I have to write a function, organizeItems, that organizes items by category. The argument to the function is an array of item objects. Each item object has 3 properties, category (string), itemName (string), and onSale (Boolean).

```js
var itemData = [
  { category: 'fruit', itemName: 'apple', onSale: false },
  { category: 'canned', itemName: 'beans', onSale: false },
  { category: 'canned', itemName: 'corn', onSale: true },
  { category: 'frozen', itemName: 'pizza', onSale: false },
  { category: 'fruit', itemName: 'melon', onSale: true },
  { category: 'canned', itemName: 'soup', onSale: false },
];
```

The return value should be an object with category properties. Each property value is an array of items that belong to that category and having onSale set to true should have '($)' appended to their item name. This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```js
{
  fruit:  ['apple', 'melon($)'],
  canned: ['beans', 'corn($)', 'soup'],
  frozen: ['pizza']
};
```

So far this is what I have:

```
var codeObj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < itemData.length; i++){
  for(key in itemData[i]){
    codeObj[itemData[i].category] = Object.values([itemData[i].itemNames])
```

This is what was outputted to the console:

```
{ fruit: [ undefined ], canned: [ undefined ], frozen: [ undefined ] }
```

Comment: Second time I'm seeing this. You're just looking for people to do your work for you. Please show use that you've at least tried something, so we can pick it up from there.

Comment: I think you need [`for... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: @MannyAlvarado I'm not looking for people to do the work for me, just a nudge in the right direction. I've tried several methods, but I just didn't post them because I usually get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I did it like so.

```
     const obj = {};
    itemData.map((item, index) => {
      let objKeys = Object.keys(item);
      objKeys.forEach((k) => {
        if (k === "category") {
          if (!obj[item[k]]) {
            obj[item[k]] = [];
          }

          if (!obj[item[k]].find((i) => i === item.itemName)) {
            obj[item[k]].push(
              item.onSale ? `${item.itemName}($)` : item.itemName
            );
          }
        }
      });
    });
    console.log("obj", obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

my  way

```js
const itemData = 
  [ { category: 'fruit',  itemName: 'apple', onSale: false } 
  , { category: 'canned', itemName: 'beans', onSale: false } 
  , { category: 'canned', itemName: 'corn',  onSale: true  } 
  , { category: 'frozen', itemName: 'pizza', onSale: false } 
  , { category: 'fruit',  itemName: 'melon', onSale: true  } 
  , { category: 'canned', itemName: 'soup',  onSale: false } 
  ] 

const result = itemData.reduce((r,{category,itemName,onSale})=>
  {
  r[category] = r[category] || []
  r[category].push( itemName + (onSale?'($)':''))
  return r
  },{})
 
// show result
console.log( JSON.stringify(result)
                 .replace(`{"`,`\nresult =\n  { `)
                 .replace(/"],"/g,`' ]\n  , `)
                 .replace(`"]}`,`' ]\n  }`)
                 .replace(/":\["/g,`: [ '`)
                 .replace(/","/g,`', '`))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works

```
function organizeItems(itemData) {
     let obj = {}
    for(i=0; i<itemData.length; i++) {
       
        let item = itemData[i]
        for(key in item) {
            if(key === 'category') {
                 if(!obj[item[key]]) {
                     obj[item[key]] = []
                 }
                 if(obj[item[key]]) {
                     obj[item[key]].push(item.onSale ? `${item.itemName}($)` : `${item.itemName}`)
                 }
            }
           
        }
    }

    return obj
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function organizeItems(items) { 
 return items.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      let itemCategory = obj.category
      if (!acc[itemCategory]) {
        acc[itemCategory]= []
    }
    acc[itemCategory].push(obj.onSale?`${obj.itemName}($)`:`${obj.itemName}`)
    return acc
    }
  }, {})
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
function organizeItems(itemData) {

    var result = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < itemData.length; i++) {

        var type = itemData[i].category;

        var name = itemData[i].itemName;

        if (itemData[i].onSale) {

            name += "($)";

        }
        if (type in result) {

            result[type].push(name);

        } else {

            result[type] = [name];
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain what did you changed and how ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).